# Angularjs $resource url intercept url encoding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a sort of file-manager application that connects to a RESTFUL file api. 
On the angular app, each file and directory is an instance of angular [`$resource`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) using the file-object property `relativePathName` as resource id .

`js
var File = $resource(url + '/:type/:id', {id: '@relativePathName', type: '@type'}, {…});`

The problem is, when updating a file resource, the `relativePathName` parameter gets url encoded, e.g. `/` becomes `%2F` which causes the server to intercept the request before it hits the actual API (I assume the server treats this as a physical address and of returns a 404 response). The API is capable of treating whole url segments as a single param, so basically it'd treat `path/to/file` as a uri parameter of `http://myapp.com/api/files/create/path/to/file` and not as a different uri.

My question is, is there a way to modify the request url after it's being generated by the [private Router instance](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource/blob/v1.2.0-rc.3/angular-resource.js#L403) inside of the resource constructor? If so, how (found nothing on this in the docs)?. What would be a possible solution? passing `relativePathName` as a parameter instead of declaring it as the resource id (which would require modifying the API)?

Thanks in advance.

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $resource is not the one stop shop for RESTful service calls, it is merely a convenience service for api's that are structured in a certain way. If $resource cannot do what you need, just create your own service using a mix of $resource and $http that that fits the api you are trying to call.

Comment: Thanks, that's probably the only way. After some tinkering I ended up extending the constructor retrieved by `$resource()` and override `$get` as this is the only method that is , in my case, critical with regards to encoded url params.

Answer (score 0):

In our app we wanted a different URL for getByName requests, so we override the resource address with the URL parameter of the action getByName like so:

```
myapp.factory('ListGroup', ['$resource',
     function($resource) {

        return $resource(
            '/API/List/:Id',
            {
                Id:'@Id',
                Name:'@Name'
            },
            {
                getByName: {method: 'GET', url: '/API/List/Group/:Name', isArray: true}
            }
        );
}
```

]);

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, is there a way to modify the request url after it's being generated by the private Router instance inside of the resource constructor?

I'm not sure about *inside* of the resource constructor but you can use [interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) to programatically alter route urls after they have been generated by $resource.

**structure**

```
hooks.config.js
hooks.factory.js
hooks.module.js
```

**hooks.module.js**

```
module.exports = angular
                    .module("app.hooks", [])
                    .factory("hooks", require("./hooks.factory.js"))
                    .config(require("./hooks.config.js"));
```

**hooks.config.js**

```
module.exports = ["$httpProvider", function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push("hooks");
}];
```

**hooks.factory.js**

```
module.exports = ["$q", "$location", function($q, $location) {

    var basePrefix = "/api/v1";

    return {
        //invoked on every http request
        request: function(request) {
            request.url = interpret(request.url);
            return $q.when(request);
        }
    };

    function interpret(str) {
        //if requesting an html template, don't do anything
        if (str.indexOf(".html") > -1)
            return str;
        //if you're accessing the api, append the base prefix globally here
        else
            return basePrefix + str;
    }
}];
```